# Frequency by Day and Month R

Tags: r, date, aggregate, frequency, cumsum

I have a large dataset...60k records covering 63 years of data.

I need to produce a plot of mean number of events per day over the 63 year period, resulting in a dataframe like:

```
Date Frequency
DDMM    5.2
```

First question - How can I convert the dates DD/MM/YYYY to DD/MM to allow for grouping

Second: What function is best to produce an average value for that day over the time span of the data set.

I have looked at aggregate and cumsum but fail miserably as I have not been able to group by DDMM and Mean Value.

Update:

```
 esums <- with(TorData,
          tapply(Count, 
                 format( as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m"), 
                 sum, na.rm=TRUE) )

Data<-esums/63
```

Results looks like this:

```
    01/01     01/02     01/03     01/04     01/05     01/06     01/07     01/08 
    0.4444444 0.6190476 2.1428571 1.8095238 4.9365079 5.4920635 4.0000000 1.7301587 
    01/09     01/10     01/11     01/12     02/01     02/02     02/03     02/04 
    1.4444444 1.1904762 0.9206349 0.4126984 0.8412698 0.7936508 2.3015873 4.9206349 
    02/05     02/06     02/07     02/08     02/09     02/10     02/11     02/12 
    4.7936508 6.4920635 3.8888889 2.0317460 1.5714286 0.7936508 0.4603175 1.0634921
```

Convert to Dataframe

```
    Data<-as.data.frame(Data)
```

The data is now on an array, and needs converting to a data frame?

```
       Data
 01/01 0.4444444
 01/02 0.6190476
 01/03 2.1428571
 01/04 1.8095238
 01/05 4.9365079
 01/06 5.4920635
 01/07 4.0000000
 01/08 1.7301587
 01/09 1.4444444
 01/10 1.1904762
 01/11 0.9206349
 01/12 0.4126984
```

What I require for the lineplot would be 2 columns one with Date and the other with Mean, Date appears to have lost its data type?

Comment: Please could someone explain why this has been voted down, Thanks!

Comment: I suspect those votes came in before you put any code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (untested in the absence of a reproducible example):

```
 esums <- with(my_dataframe,
            tapply(event_count, 
                   format( as.Date(my_dates, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m"), 
                   sum, na.rm=TRUE) )
 enums <-  with(my_dataframe,
            tapply(event_count[!is.na(event_count)], 
                   format( as.Date(my_dates, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m"), 
                   sum, na.rm=TRUE) )
 mean_by_day_of_year <- esums/enums
```

The dataframe you created has factor values (since without years they are not really Dates and there is no day-of-the-year datatype and `as.data.frame` turns the d/m's into rownames.) You can plot then as a line plot using the sequence index as the x value, set xaxt="n", and then plot an informative labeling with `axis(1, ...)`.

```
   dat <- read.table(text=    "Data
 01/01 0.4444444
  01/02 0.6190476
  01/03 2.1428571
  01/04 1.8095238
  01/05 4.9365079
  01/06 5.4920635
  01/07 4.0000000
  01/08 1.7301587
  01/09 1.4444444
  01/10 1.1904762
  01/11 0.9206349
  01/12 0.4126984", header=TRUE)
 plot(dat$Data, xaxt="n")
 axis(1, at=1:nrow(dat), labels=rownames(dat), las=2)
 png(); plot(dat$Data, xaxt="n")
        axis(1, at=1:nrow(dat), labels=rownames(dat), las=2)
 dev.off()
```

[image: >]

Comment: Getting somewhere esums/63 works to give me an average number of events on that day over the 63 year period..Thanks!

Comment: Now I need to plot mean against date but when I put the results into a dataframe I do not get 2 columns required? i.e. Date and Mean how do I convert the data into that format? Thanks Again

Comment: Still no test objects. Also not showing the code or error messages. Not able to help much without them.

Comment: format( as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m/%d"), allows for the correct order when plotting the data "%d/%m" did not work...thanks again for your help. I hate dates in all programming languages!

Comment: Heh. Dates _are_ a pain. And the plotting of factors in R can be a pain, too, and I think that could screw things up if the days of the month are the leading digits. By default (poor design IMO) the character data gets input as factors. Probably should have used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when doing the `read.table`.